# Detecting (from browser extension) whether my mouse movements are being tracked by some javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to detect (via javascript) whether there are, in the page, other javascript scripts listening to my mouse movements?

I suspect I can do it by inspecting the DOM listeners, but I am not sure.

Thanks